# Simple class as a binding data source

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I created a demo project with a working two-way data binding between my MainWindow and a runtime created child object derived from UserControl and INotifyPropertyChanged with a TextBox on top. My source was a private `List<Byte>` on my MainWindow.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private List<Byte> buffer;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Binding binding;
        binding = new Binding("Buffer");
        binding.ElementName = "window";
        binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

        myEdit = new MyEdit();
        myEdit.SetBinding(MyEdit.BufferValueProperty, binding);
    }

    public List<Byte> Buffer
    {
        get
        {
            return this.buffer;
        }

        set
        {
            this.buffer = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Buffer");
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to implement this into my real project. But my data source is not in the MainWindow, it is within another simple class without XAML code.

```
public class SimpleClass: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<Byte> buffer;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public SimpleClass()
    {
        this.buffer = new List<Byte>();

        Binding binding;
        binding = new Binding("Buffer");
        binding.ElementName = "?????????";
        binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

        myEdit = new MyEdit();
        myEdit.SetBinding(MyEdit.BufferValueProperty, binding);
    }
}
```

My question is, where can I get the ElementName for the binding? Is it possible to do it in that way?

Comment: why dont you directly bind in xaml `<TextBox text=binding someproperty/>`

Comment: When using WPF you really want to use the MVVM pattern. If you arn't using MVVM, there is a good chance you will create more work for yourself. That seems to be the case here. As @Eldho pointed out, this is much simpler to bind using xaml.

Comment: `myEdit.SetBinding` - this is not how WPF data binding is supposed to be used. You should not create and assign a Binding in the source class, i.e. the view model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of ElementName set Source directly. You also need to define `Buffer` property. Binding won't work with a field.

```
public class SimpleClass: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<Byte> buffer;
    public List<Byte> Buffer { get { return buffer; } set { buffer = value; } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public SimpleClass()
    {
        this.buffer = new List<Byte>();

        Binding binding = new Binding("Buffer");
        binding.Source = this;
        binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

        myEdit = new MyEdit();
        myEdit.SetBinding(MyEdit.BufferValueProperty, binding);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even simpler: `public List<Byte> Buffer { get; } = new List<Byte>();` No need for a backing field. Besides that INotifyPropertyChanged is pointless. The PropertyChanged event is never fired here.

Comment: @Clemens, I would make get-only property, but then `BindingMode.TwoWay` will crash if there is an attempt to update property. Besides, not everyone works with the newest c# version

Comment: Ok, then `public List<Byte> Buffer { get; set; } = new List<Byte>();` should work. The whole thing doesn't make sense anyway.

Comment: Many thanks for that. I think I do a rework of my project